# Как указать свой шаблон для пагинации?

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Как в LinkPager yii2 выводить такой шаблон

```
<ul class="pagination-custom row flex-center">
  <div class="col-1">
    <li>
      <a class="not-active" href="">
        < Предыдущая</a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 flex-center">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <li><a href="#">Следующая ></a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот прямо задать шаблон нельзя, так как этот виджет использует свой шаблон, который работает на bootstrap-е. (В свое время тоже долго мучился). Но вы можете максимально приблизить пагинатор используя опции виджета, и обернуть его в свой класс, а затем с помощью css довести внешний вид до нужного вам. Вот пример использования опций этого виджета:
https://www.codevoila.com/post/12/yii2-listview-example-customizing-pagination